# can an almost perfect number not be a power of 2

Tags: number-theory

we define an almost perfect number as any number n such that sigma(n)=2n-1. in other words, the sum of the proper divisors of n is 1 less than the number itself. It is known that all powers of 2 are almost perfect numbers. Is it possible for an almost perfect number to not be a power of 2?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article? This is an open problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number